# How to prohibit NULL being passed in an argument list when std::string is the parameter?

Tags: c++

So I ran into a bug today where a NULL was passed into a constructor's argument list and this caused the application to break. Its odd that the compiler did not prohibit this from happening. Since the argument list changed, the problem was not noticed until now. See the following code snippet:

This object takes 3 parameters, pay close attention to std::string&.

```
class Foo {
public: 
    std::string myName;
    unsigned int someVariable;
    void * ptr;

    Foo(const std::string&  name, void * aPtr, unsigned int variable);
    ~Foo();
}

Foo::Foo(const std::string&  name, void * aPtr, unsigned int variable) : myName(name), ptr(aPtr), someVariable(variable)
{
   // object constructed
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   // construct an instance of Foo
   Foo foo(NULL /*whoops, passed in NULL when a string should be passed in*/,
           "foo", 
           0);   // program compiles as expected, A NULL pointer runtime error occurs when executed.
}
```

So basically, if you accidently switch your input values for your foo object the compiler does not do anything. No alarm is sounded and you are left scratching your head what happened when the program crashes. I would think there should be a way to prevent this from occurring. Is there something that works around this issue? Is there something in the compiler that should be turned on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, it's not really `NULL` that is being passed by reference.

`std::string` has a converting constructor that takes a `char const*`.  `NULL` is a null pointer constant, so it can be used where a `char const*` is expected, so a `std::string` object is constructed from this null pointer.  This construction yields undefined behavior.

One option for providing a better warning to the user would be to add another constructor that has a `char const*` parameter.  This way you can easily add an assert in the constructor if null is passed in.  It's not a compile-time check, but it might be better than nothing if your run into this problem frequently (for what it's worth, I can't recall ever having run into this problem, so I'd argue that it's not worth the effort).

Comment: Why does it yield undefined behavior?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The argument to that particular `std::string` constructor cannot be NULL in the contract.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  The specification of `std::basic_string` requires that the pointer not be null.

Comment: This is why many people prefer explicit constructors. They avoid this kind of error - if the `std::string` constructor taking a pointer was made explicit, the compiler would have generated the expected error. (or was it a constructor that took `int`?)

Comment: @MarkRansom:  It would have, but then it adds substantial verbosity to code that deals with a lot of strings or with multiple different kinds of string types.  I'm okay with this implicit conversion.  A good `std::basic_string` implementation could assert on invalid constructor arguments anyway.

Comment: You could also declare such a constructor private without defining it, or use `=delete` from C++11, if available.  This will cause a compile-time failure rather than a run-time assert.

Comment: Create a private constructor which takes a int as the first parameter. Now when somebody passes NULL, they will get an "inaccessible constructor" error. You may want to do the same with nullptr_t.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas & James I didn't know that. Just assumed it returns an empty string (though, to be fair, I never actually used a NULL as param).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, that's why I said "many people". I don't get bitten by this problem either, so I prefer the convenience of non-explicit constructors myself.

Comment: If using c++0x one could use static_assert, couldnt he?

Comment: @Paranaix:  How could one use `static_assert` here?  `static_assert` is evaluated at compile-time and can only evaluate constant expressions.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That is adding cost for almost nothing... The only case where one can unintentionally pass NULL as an `int` is `NULL` or `0` (literal). All other `int` values won't convert to `const char*`, so the cases where it would catch an error aren't that many. At the same time, a `const char*` can be NULL, and that would still be unnoticed. An `assert` is (opinion) the way to go. I have never encountered that error, does it really need solving? Now, if we talk about the *whole* `string` interface... I would gladly remove `operator=( CharT )`, which allows the same type of errors...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez at least it solves the stated problem of detecting the error (passing NULL) at compile time.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Don't forget to add equivalent overloads to each and every function that takes a `const char*` in the `std::string` interface, and since you are at it, also those that take iterators, as a pointer is a proper iterator, but NULL is not a valid argument for any of them... Note that the error is not the implicit conversion, but an error in the position of the arguments at the place of call, which in this case caused the implicit conversion to trigger. Will you create unique types for each argument to every function so that the compiler can always catch this problem in all cases?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
    Foo(const std::string&  name, void * aPtr, unsigned int variable);
    ~Foo();
private:
    Foo(int, void*, unsigned int); // Do not implement.
                                   // This will generate a link time error when
                                   // NULL is used as the first parameter.
```

Note: I get compiler errors anyway without this change (so this is obviously not the code you are running). But when I fix the obvious mistakes I still get:

```
n.cpp:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’
// This is caused by the parameter -> "foo"
```